# How to setup anonymous NFS correctly

Tags: ubuntu, nfs

I set up an NFS server on Ubuntu Server 12.04 for my linux based DVB-S receiver (Spark 7162)
Unfortunately the receiver is only able to connect anonymously. Directories are created but can not be written to because the permissions are not sufficient:

```
drw-r--r-- 2 receiver receiver 4096 Feb  8 22:49 @Law & Order_ Special Victims Unit_1
```

Because of this writing broadcasts to NFS fails.
This is the content of my /etc/fstab:

```
/home   /export/users   none    bind,umask=000   0      0
```

I toyed around with fmask=0 and dmask=0 but this didn't help either.
Both the /export and the /export/users directory are set up this way:

> drwxrwxrwx   3 receiver receiver  4096 Feb  8 18:08 export

This is the content of my /etc/exports:

```
/export/users   192.168.0.0/24(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,async,anonuid=1001,anongid=1001)
```

In the .profile of user "receiver" I set umask 000

What am I doing wrong ? Even although I set permissions very generously I simply can't get the directory permissions right and write to it.

Comment: Remove the umask.

Comment: Do you mean both (.profile and fstab) ? By the way: I didn't set the umask in the beginning, I added them later with the intention to solve the problem

Comment: both. it's not doing any good.  Try adding `all_squash` to your exports. (make everyone anon) Perhaps the receiver is setting the permissions wrong. (I'm not going to walk anyone through debugging NFS requests)

Comment: Also, the user account on the NFS server is not referenced by the NFS server. (uid's in the fs don't have to have an account in passwd; they only have to have meaning on the mounting system)